# How to make program run until user inputs a specfic key

Tags: java

How do I make this program run until the user enters a specific key, lets say x, to terminate the program?

```
public class NestedLoopTableApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       
       System.out.println("Input Table Numbers [one at a time]");
    
       int valueOne = sc.nextInt();
       int valueTwo = sc.nextInt();
       

       NestedLoopTable np = new NestedLoopTable(valueOne, valueTwo);
       np.printTable();
       sc.close();
      
   }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add your code block into the while loop and add a condition

```
while(sc.nextLine().equals("x")) { 
//...... your code here
}
```

Thanks,
Vijay Kareliya

Comment: You cannot use `nextInt()` method to get a non-numerical value like "X", can you? I think it is better to use `nextLine()` method and get the input String and then try to cast it to `Integer`.